# how to get form inputs on delete endpoint in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have the following endpoint

```
Route::prefix('traffic-table')->group(function() {
      Route::delete('/{id_olt}', 'Api\TrafficTableController@remove');
   });
```

And I want to obtain the request parameters like this:

```
public function remove($id_olt, Request $request)
{
    return response()->json($request->all());
}
```

which return an empty array.Here is my curl call:

```
curl --location --request DELETE 'localhost/api/traffic-table/41' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer 2|jY4c7vBFTTG9Jb0cW1NAgm6Kr0gTFLeJO9t9Nu8I' \
--form 'id="1010"'
```

How could I obtain the id (besides sending it through the url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using --form, try using the following

```
--data "id=1010"
```

Then you can use `$request->input('id')` to retrieve it.

Let me know how you go.